# Cancer Survivor Family Friend Visiting UK

Tags: international-travel, health

I have a question on what medical documents should a family friend bring to UK, if they happen to be Cancer Survivors? An year ago he was diagnosed with cancer and he has undergone treatment. The doctors have given him the clean bill of health & he is now well into the recovery period after undergoing chemotherapy and radiotherapy. He is coming to UK on a standard visit visa and he will be spending time with me for a month. I am bringing him over here to give him a break from things. What specific documents should I ask him to bring, should he have any problems?

- So far, I have asked him to bring his medical file detailing all the treatment he has undergone so far.
- Also, I have asked him to get the prescriptions for the medicines he is currently taking
- His doctor has also given a letter stating his condition right now and what treatment he has undergone. The letter also explains that he is fit to travel.

Are there any other documents, I should be asking him to bring? I am sure he will be fine, but I am just thinking about the most unfortunate of circumstances & how can I help mitigate the risk of not having enough information for any unforeseen treatments here.

Regards,S

Comment: You seem to have covered all the bases; additionally, he should obtain comprehensive travel & medical insurance, one that covers pre-existing conditions.

Comment: What specifically are you concerned about? Is the concern more with having sufficient documentation to demonstrate to British immigration officials that the friend is healthy enough to visit the UK? Are the documents primarily to help him maintain continuity of care in the UK? Are the documents expected to be needed only in case of emergency?

Comment: @Srikumar S Agree with Giorgio regarding comprehensive medical insurance for pre-existing conditions, only accident&emergency treatments (excluding hospital admissions) are free to non EU visitors https://www.nhs.uk/NHSEngland/AboutNHSservices/uk-visitors/visiting-england/Pages/visitors-from-outside-the-eea.aspx

Comment: thanks a lot all.. that certainly alleviate most of my concerns. To @Giorgio's point about insurance, I am already in the process of looking it up. Would any of you have any recommendations on which insurance companies do offer preexisting conditions coverage?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have covered all the bases; additionally, he should obtain comprehensive travel & medical insurance, one that covers pre-existing conditions.

A cautionary note when seeking entry at the border: a large stack of medical records (paper, electronic, medications, physician's testament) may concern an Immigration Officer who may ask for clarification that he is not planning to seek treatment in the UK. Should the need arise, he would want to have with him proof that he has the funds to pay for any treatment, support, accommodation without relying on public funds.